# Angular - same ng-template on more places in one component

Tags: angular, ng-template

Two kendo-comboxes with a same data source. Is there any way how to reuse ng-template from the first combobox into the second combobox ? Thank you :)

```
<kendo-combobox #customerComboboxFrom [data]="customersData" [valueField]="'Name'" [textField]="'Name'" [(ngModel)]="journey.FromCustomer">
        <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem #customerOverview>
          <img [src]="dataItem.PhotoUrl" alt="">
          <div class="CustomerDetail">
            <span>{{dataItem.Name}}</span>
            <span class="lighter">{{dataItem.State}}, {{dataItem.Country}}, {{dataItem.District}}</span>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-combobox>
      <kendo-combobox #customerComboboxTo [data]="customersData" [valueField]="'Name'" [textField]="'Name'" [(ngModel)]="journey.FromCustomer">
      -----------  //Is there any way how to reuse HERE ng-template #customerOverview from above ?
      </kendo-combobox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the template in the second combobox with a [template outlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet). As an alternative, the template could be defined outside of the comboboxes and inserted in the definition of both comboboxes.

```
<kendo-combobox #customerComboboxFrom [data]="customersData" ... >
  <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem #customerOverview>
    <img [src]="dataItem.PhotoUrl" alt="">
    <div class="CustomerDetail">
      <span>{{dataItem.Name}}</span>
      <span class="lighter">
        {{dataItem.State}}, {{dataItem.Country}}, {{dataItem.District}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-combobox>

<kendo-combobox #customerComboboxTo [data]="customersData" ... >
  <ng-template kendoComboBoxItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="customerOverview; context: { $implicit: dataItem }">
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>    
</kendo-combobox>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-combobox-textfield-binding-multiple-properties-numfdf) for a demo.

Comment: I just simplified my answer, so that you can just reuse the template defined in the first combobox.